# I don't know how to combine my attributes into a single column for this query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

My query is to Produce a list of `Employees` who work for the `cinema` with the `cinema number 07` and include the `cinema name` in the result. Arrange the result in `ascending order by employee surname`. `Name` attributes should be combined into a single output column, and given a sensible header.
I've answered most of the query but I'm stuck on the last part . Can somebody help me on this .

```
  SELECT Employee.Cinema_No, Cinema.Cinema_Name, Employee.First_Name, 
  Employee.Surname
  FROM Employee
  INNER JOIN Cinema ON Employee.Cinema_No = Cinema.Cinema_No
  WHERE Employee.Cinema_No = 7
  ORDER BY Surname ASC ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that is left to do is to concatenate the First and Last name of the employee into a single column. For this, Oracle provides the `||` operator (string concatenation). You can then use an alias to choose a sensible column name, using keyword `AS`.

Query :

```
SELECT 
    Employee.Cinema_No, 
    Cinema.Cinema_Name, 
    Employee.First_Name || ' ' ||  Employee.Surname AS Employee_Full_Name
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN Cinema ON Employee.Cinema_No = Cinema.Cinema_No
WHERE Employee.Cinema_No = 7
ORDER BY Surname ASC ;
```

Comment: Welcome @Sharad

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

I initially answered this question without realizing it was targetting Oracle. So, if you happened to need a similar query for MS SQL Server you can find the original answer below...

I think your query is fine. You only need to combine the employee's name like below...

```
  SELECT Employee.Cinema_No, 
      Cinema.Cinema_Name, 
      Employee.First_Name + " " + Employee.Surname as FullName
  FROM Employee
  INNER JOIN Cinema ON Employee.Cinema_No = Cinema.Cinema_No
  WHERE Employee.Cinema_No = 7
  ORDER BY Surname ASC ;
```

Comment: this is Oracle, the '+' operator is for number addition, not string concatenation. Your query will generate error `ORA-01722: Ìnvalid number`

Comment: Welcome Leo, SQL engines have so many such differences we all get screwed sometimes

Comment: @GMB I'll upvote your answer and leave this one as a MS SQL Server version in case some needs it

Answer (score 0):

[`Concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm) syntax can help you..

*Definition*:

> CONCAT returns char1 concatenated with char2. Both char1 and char2 can
>   be any of the datatypes CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, NVARCHAR2, CLOB, or
>   NCLOB.

```
SELECT 
  Employee.Cinema_No, 
  Cinema.Cinema_Name, 
  Concat(Employee.First_Name, ' ', Employee.Surname) as Named
FROM 
  Employee
  INNER JOIN Cinema ON Employee.Cinema_No = Cinema.Cinema_No
WHERE 
  Employee.Cinema_No = 7
ORDER BY 
  Surname ASC ;
```